# Hbase storage for table format

Tags: hbase

I need to store logs generated from web server (say, Tomcat) in HBase tables.
Please define me the correct format for Column Families, Keyvalues etc.
I am going to store values like ipaddress, log data and log levels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no correct format here.
- In HBase column family design is generally done through phrasing your queries first and then columns/column families along with the row key is decided based on the query requirements. This is one key difference between the old RDBMS way and the NoSQL way.
- Remember as I know HBase does not support secondary indexes. Hence selection of your Rowkey is the major design element that will affect the performance of your query.